# Relational Column values does not get populated after data retrieval from database?

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using **Database First** approach to generate models from existing database. To do so i run this command successfully

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I get all the models and a context file. 
**Problem:**
When i try to retrieve data from database using **Context.tableName** all the values of model are populated except relational fields. For example

```
        public DateTime? DateCreation { get; set; }
        public double? Discount { get; set; }
        public double? Rate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }

        public virtual Packaging Packaging { get; set; }
```

Here, `Packaging` remains always NULL, even though data exists in the related table for this entry. Here is the relevant code from context file

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Packaging)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PackagingLogs)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PackagingId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_PackagingLogs_Packaging");
```

There may be something i am missing here but it never works for me in any model. Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you must either eagerly or explicitly load the relationship. This won't happen automatically for you. For example:

```
_context.Foos.Include(x => x.Packaging)
```

You can opt to *lazy* load instead, but that must be explictly enabled:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o => o.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
      .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

However, lazy loading will end up issuing a query for the relationship JIT (just in time) when the reference property is accessed. That means you can easily end up with an N+1 query scenario where you end up spamming your DB with queries. You should always eagerly load any relationships you intend to utilize with `Include` as the preferred approach.